# Can we open/run a file/executable in Finder using the keyboard?

Tags: finder, high-sierra, mojave

In Windows, we can select a file/executable in Explorer and on pressing Enter with the keyboard, the file/executable is opened. Is this feature available on Mac OS? In Finder, if a file/executable is selected with the mouse and then we press Enter, it wants to rename the file.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

On macOS, to open the selected item, press:

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> (letter "o")
- or: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> (down arrow)

Alternatively, to Quick Look the selected item press:

- <kbd>Space</kbd>
- Then <kbd>space</kbd> again to close Quick Look.

Comment: You can also press cmd + down arrow

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Thanks, I didn't know this shortcut. I guess the logic behind is going one folder backward (arrow up) / forward (arrow down). Kind of a zoom in, zoom out movement, with "opening" as a last "zoom in" operation.

Comment: I was asking myself: is this really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

PresButan 1.4 worked for me on Mac OS Mojave (http://briankendall.net/presButan/index.htm). I had to manually add it to System Preferences -> Security and privacy -> Privacy -> Accessibility -> Allow below apps to control your computer

[image]

PS: I am not Brian Kendall.

Comment: If you are Brian Kendall, (the author of this daemon app,) please add an attribution to your post.